# Back fill timeseries data in SQL

Tags: sql, time-series, vertica

I have data in a SQL (Vertica) database table that looks like this...

```
      ts  src val
---------------------------------
10:25:10    C  72
10:25:09    A  13
10:25:08    A  99
10:25:05    B  22
10:25:02    C  71
```

I need to "rotate" it into columns and backfill the last known value by the `src` column like so.

```
      ts a_val b_val c_val
----------------------------
10:25:10    13    22    72
10:25:09    13    22    71
10:25:08    99    22    71
10:25:05  null    22    71
10:25:02  null  null    71
```

I know all the possible values of the `src` ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is with correlated subqueries.  This won't necessarily have the best performance:

```
select t.ts,
       (select t2.val from table t2 where t2.ts <= t.ts and t2.src = 'a' order by t2.ts desc) as val_a,
       (select t2.val from table t2 where t2.ts <= t.ts and t2.src = 'b' order by t2.ts desc) as val_b,
       (select t2.val from table t2 where t2.ts <= t.ts and t2.src = 'c' order by t2.ts desc) as val_c
from table t;
```

An index on `table(ts, src, val)` might help the subqueries in a database other than Vertica.

Comment: Vertica doesn't use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic functions.  Something like:

```
SELECT ts
, src
, MIN(val) val
FROM (
    SELECT ts
    , src
    , first_value(val) OVER (
        PARTITION BY src 
        ORDER BY ts 
        ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
      ) val
    FROM table
) tab
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```